# sql pivot data rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table similar to the one below. Its a table of items and their related bin locations. Some may have more than one bin location and all of them will have a preferred or primary bin location. How can I run a query to transpose the rows to columns and identifying which the preferred bin as the first?

```
Item   Bin   Preferred
A      2       Yes
A      3       No
A      1       No
B      3       Yes
B      4       No
```

The output should look like this:

```
Item   BinPreferred  Bin2 Bin3
 A     2               3    1
 B     3               4    -
```

I have tried using the PIVOT function with no luck.

Thanks,

Comment: Since you have tsql as a tag, is this SQL Server? If so, what version?

Comment: What is logic of `Bin3`?

Comment: Is there a fixed limit on the number of bins an item can be in? Or is it dynamic?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? List your `PIVOT` code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solution for case that one item has maximal number of 3 bins.
It will select main bin and two other that are not equal,if i am right.

```
Select distinct 
mainbin.item,
mainbin.bin as binpreffered,
bin2.bin as bin2,
bin3.bin as bin3 
from table mainbin  
left join table bin2 on (mainbin.id=bin2.id)
left join table bin3 on (mainbin.id=bin3.id)
where mainbin.preffered='Yes' 
and bin2.preffered='No' 
and bin3.preffered='No'
and bin2.id<>bin3.id;
```